# Cannot get Accordion working

Tags: angular, accordion, ng2-bootstrap

I cannot get the Accordion component to work. I have this in my app.module.ts:

```
 //ng2-bootstrap
    import { AccordionModule } from "ng2-bootstrap";

    @NgModule({
        declarations: [...],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,        
        HttpModule,
        FormsModule,                
        ...
        AccordionModule
    ]...
```

I am using systemjs for modules, so my config is:

```
var map = {
    'app': 'app', // 'dist',
    '@angular': 'dist/lib/@angular',
    'moment': 'dist/lib/moment/min/moment.min.js',
    'ng2-bootstrap': 'dist/lib/ng2-bootstrap',
    'angular2-in-memory-web-api': 'dist/lib/angular2-in-memory-web-api',
    'rxjs': 'dist/lib/rxjs',
    'ag-grid-ng2': 'dist/lib/ag-grid-ng2',
    'ag-grid-enterprise': 'dist/lib/ag-grid-enterprise',
    'ag-grid': 'dist/lib/ag-grid'
};

// packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
var packages = {
    'app': { main: 'main.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'ng2-bootstrap': {
        format: 'cjs',
        main: 'bundles/ng2-bootstrap.umd.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
    },...
```

I have this markup in one of my components:

```
<accordion>
<accordion-group heading="Static Header, initially expanded"
                                         [isOpen]="status.isFirstOpen"
                                         [isDisabled]="status.isFirstDisabled">
                            This content is straight in the template.
</accordion-group>
</accordion>
```

Angular 2 is not happy with my markup. It cannot figure out what to do with the Accordion markup:

```
Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'isOpen' since it isn't a known property of 'accordion-group'.
1. If 'accordion-group' is an Angular component and it has 'isOpen' input, then verify that it is part of this module.
```

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong? I'm close to giving up on this library.
Thanks.

Comment: what version of `ng2-bootstrap`are you running?

Comment: And did you try `AccordionModule.forRoot()` in `ngModules` imports?

Comment: Yes, I have a version for forRoot().
When I use forRoot(), I have to change my import to:

`import {AccordionModule} from "ng2-bootstrap/accordion";`

I'm using 1.2.5

Answer (score 0):

Please upgrade your ngx-bootstrap

```
npm i ngx-bootstrap@2.0.5 --save
```

or

```
npm i ngx-bootstrap@4.2.0 --save
```